# Template filter + if tag

Tags: django

I have applied a template filter, which extracts the domain from an email address. In the template file I have this code:

```
{% for email in user_list %}

<p> 
{{email.email}} corresponds to this domain: 

<b> {{email.email|domain}} </b>
</p>

{% endfor %}
```

It is currently making bold all domain names. What I want to do is to make bold ONLY those email addresses with a 'valid' email extension (for example, only those at the domain '@gmail.com'). How do I apply an if or ifequal statement to do this?

For example, this is the logic I want it to have --

```
{% for email in user_list %}

<p> 
{{email.email}} corresponds to this domain: 

    {% if domain = 'specified extension' %}
    <b> {{email.email|domain}} </b>
    {% else %}
    {{ email.email|domain }}
    {% endif %}

</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Update:

OK -- I got this working by creating a custom model in `models.py`, like so --

```
class Table(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def valid_email(self):
        verified = ['yahoo.com','gmail.com']
        domain = self.email.split('@')[1]
        return domain in verified
```

And in the template `index.html` --

```
{% for email in user_list %}

<p> 
{{email.email}} corresponds to this domain: 

    {% if email.valid_email %}
    <b>{{ email.email|domain}}</b>
    {% else %}
    {{ email.email|domain}}
    {% endif %}
</p>

{% endfor %}
```

This works well now, but my concern is that when I need to update the `models.py` and tamper with the verified email list. Where would be a better place to hold this `valid_emails()` function, such that I can update it easily? And then how would I reference the function in the template (if different than current)? Thank you.

Comment: Don't hard-code those valid domains in your template!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [`with` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#with) to assign `email.email|domain` to `domain`.

```
<p> 
{{ email.email }} corresponds to this domain: 
  {% with domain=email.email|domain %} 
    {% if domain = 'specified extension' %}
    <b>{{ domain }}</b>
    {% else %}
    {{ domain }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
</p>
```

Note that I've used the Django 1.3 `with` syntax. See the docs for earlier versions of Django.

To follow up on Ben James' comment, if you set a list of specified_extensions in the view, you can use [`in` operator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#in-operator) in your `if` statement.

**In the view:**

```
specified_extensions = ['gmail.com', 'hotmail.com',]
```

**In the template:**

```
{% if domain in specified_extensions %}
...
```

### Update:

I think that you have put the `valid_emails` method in the correct place, it belongs on the model. If you want to be able to update the list of domains without restarting the server, I suggest you store the domains in the database.

```
class VerifiedDomain(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="an allowed domain name for emails, e.g 'gmail.com'")

class Table(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def valid_email(self):
        domain = self.email.split('@')[1]
        return VerifiedDomain.objects.filter(name=domain).exists()
```

Comment: ruby is so much better at this. Anyway, I've always used filters in such situations.

Comment: with: like in javascript 3.1

Comment: `with` command is wrong. you have to assign variable first ie `{% with domain=email.email|domain %} `

Comment: @suhailvs thanks, I've fixed it now. I'm surprised it took 8 years for someone to leave a comment that the code was wrong!

Answer (score 2):

To keep the logic (of what makes a "valid" domain) separate from your template, you could write a Python function `valid_domain(domain)` (returning a boolean) and use this in a [custom template filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
@register.filter
def bold_valid_domains(domain, autoescape=None):
    def esc(text):
        return conditional_escape(text) if autoescape else text
    if valid_domain(domain):
        result = "<b>%s</b>" % (esc(domain),)
    else:
        result = domain
    return mark_safe(result)
bold_valid_domains.needs_autoescape = True
```